# Is this workflow acceptable UI for iPhone?

Tags: iphone

I have an arrow that points to the bottom for each table cell. When you click on a table cell, the screen doesn't move to another screen. Rather, the bottom picker changes depending on which cell you selected.

Is this workflow acceptable according to Apple, or does it break guidelines?
[image]

Comment: Hi. Stack Overflow is only meant for questions about programming. This is about design, and mostly just about Apple's guidelines. It will probably be closed shortly.

Comment: There’s a dedicated Stack Exchange site called [User Experience](http://ux.stackexchange.com/), that’s a perfect fit for such question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is **not** against the apple gui guidelines, and you are free to do this as you like.